# Does POSIX sh require expanding $! in order to keep a reference to the child process?

Tags: shell, posix, background-process, job-control, wait

### Spec

According to [this online POSIX Spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), in Shell & Utilities, Shell Command Language, Section 2.9.3 Lists has the following to say about Asynchronous Lists:

> When an element of an asynchronous list (the portion of the list ended
> by an <ampersand>, such as *command1*, above) is started by the shell,
> the process ID of the last command in the asynchronous list element
> shall become known in the current shell execution environment; see
> Shell Execution Environment. This process ID shall remain known until:
>
> - The command terminates and the application waits for the process ID.
> - Another asynchronous list is invoked before "`$!`" (corresponding to the
>   previous asynchronous list) is expanded in the current execution
>   environment.
>
> The implementation need not retain more than the {CHILD_MAX} most
> recent entries in its list of known process IDs in the current shell
> execution environment.

Other relevant quotations:

- From idem., Section 2.12 Shell Execution Environment:

  > A shell execution environment consists of the following:
  >
  > […]
  >
  > - Process IDs of the last commands in asynchronous lists known to this shell environment; see Asynchronous Lists
- From Shell & Utilities, Utilities, wait:

  > When an asynchronous list (see Asynchronous Lists) is started by the shell, the process ID of the last command in each element of the asynchronous list shall become known in the current shell execution environment; see Shell Execution Environment.
  >
  > […]
  >
  > If the wait utility is invoked with no operands, it shall wait until all process IDs known to the invoking shell have terminated and exit with a zero exit status.
  >
  > […]
  >
  > The known process IDs are applicable only for invocations of wait in the current shell execution environment.

### Confusion

In Bash, `help wait` specifies "all currently active child processes."

The spec specifies only all known process IDs, and it seems that that invoking another async list causes the process ID to be "forgotten."

That would make the following program only wait for 5 seconds if I've interpreted the POSIX spec correctly:

```
#! /bin/sh
sleep 10 &
sleep 5 &
wait
```

Since no use of `$!` appears before `sleep 5 &`, is the ID for `sleep 10` forgotten and not waited on?

Similarly, inserting `: $!` between the two lines would cause it to not be forgotten, right?

Let me try to lay out my logic a little more clearly:

1. SPEC: The known proc. IDs are part of the shell execution environment. Let's imagine this is some list, since implementation details don't matter.
2. SPEC: Running `command &` causes the proc. ID for this asynchronous `command` to be "known" (*i.e.*, in the list).

   - SPEC (dubiously, but see the very first quote): Running `command2 &` without expanding `$!` in some way causes the proc. ID for the previous command to become *no longer known*! (But the proc. ID for `command2` is now known.)
3. SPEC: `wait` with no arguments uses only the known proc. IDs.
4. Conclusion: Therefore, not forcing expansion of `$!` between asynchronous commands causes `wait` to forget to wait on some child processes.

Some have argued that `wait` waits on all processes. The spec says "known" processes, which has a specific definition. Some have argued that "known" refers to "in $!" even though the spec says no such thing (and further, "known process IDs" is a plural quantity while `$!` is not).

I agree this makes no practical sense; a shell doesn't forget about my jobs when I start a new one. So where am I misreading the spec?

### Question

- Does POSIX actually require using `$!` in order for `wait` with no arguments to behave sensibly, such as when starting asynchronous lists in a loop?
- Does any shell (POSIX or otherwise) actually implement the spec in such a way (*i.e.*, practically, can I avoid adding `: $! expand async. proc. ID to prevent forgetting it` to programs that use nullary `wait`)?

Comment: FWIW, I tried with all the shells I have, namely Bash, Dash, yash, zsh, mksh, ksh93, Busybox sh and heirloom-sh, and they all seem to wait for both sleeps in `sh -c 'sleep 5 & sleep 1 & wait'`.

Answer (score 0):

When you start two background jobs, `$!` is first set to the PID of the first job, then that of the second.  This does not mean that the shell loses track of the first job.  The shell is also not really concerned about what you do with `$!`.

Notice how the standard text says that `wait` with no argument will wait for *all* background jobs? This is regardless of the number of background jobs started and what you do or don't do with the `$!` parameter.

The example that you show with two sleep calls running in the background is guaranteed to wait for both calls to terminate, meaning it would take 10 seconds for the `wait` call to return.

Comment: "it shall wait until all **process IDs known to the invoking shell** have terminated" and "This process ID shall **remain known until […] Another asynchronous list is invoked before "$!" (corresponding to the previous asynchronous list) is expanded** in the current execution environment." (emph. mine) Can you see why I might think differently than your answer? What in those statements supports your answer? (I think practically you are correct, but it doesn't appear to be what's written unless I'm missing something.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The process ID is known (in `$!`) until one uses `wait` to wait for the job, or another background job is started (that process' PID is then placed in `$!`). This is what happens and what my answer says.

Comment: Hm. I'm interpreting "known" here to mean "part of an auxiliary list of child processes maintained as part of the shell's environment" (but not as in "environment variables"). The spec seems to support that interpretation. Thus, the value of `$!` is immaterial; the question is what happens to this auxiliary list when starting a second async. command but not having expanded `$!`? The spec says the process ID will no longer be known (in said list), I think?

Comment: To be clear: I _want_ to be wrong. I just can't see how to read the text in the way that we all agree is what happens in practice.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Your first quote only concerns the `$!` variable and for long its value is valid.

Comment: But, "A shell execution environment consists of the following […] Process IDs of the last commands in asynchronous lists known to this shell environment; see Asynchronous Lists". That's process IDs, plural. No mention of `$!`. ?

Comment: The Bash built-in `jobs -l` will reveal that the shell keeps internally a full list of running async processes. All you lose by not yourself saving `$!` after each `&` is that you cannot then reliably discover which specific job is which, because `$!` is ephemeral.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That section also does not mention any other variable by name.

Comment: I don't see how it's at all obvious the first quote only refers to `$!`. The wording does seem to imply that the shell might forget about the PID if the script doesn't care. That does seem an odd idea, but based on that text, it's hard to reject the hypothesis that the allowance might be there.

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, "the process ID of the last command [...]" is literally what `$!` is. See the [Special Parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) section.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, that one last PID. But why does it say "become known" (rather vaguely) if it only means "available in `$!`"? Also note how it follows with "implementation need not retain more than the {CHILD_MAX} most recent entries in its list of known process IDs", while `$!` is just one PID.